# Checksum MD5 to generate row number in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, md5, checksum

I am trying to execute the below query which was found in my error report.

Error report is generated when we try to run a R package. This error report helps us know where is the error and how it can be reproduced. Upon investigation, I was able to see that it is below query which caused issue while R package execution.

```
select co.*, p.*,
      row_number() over (order by ABS(CHECKSUM(MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT || CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()::TEXT))) % 123456789) rn
    from s1.depat co
    join s2.person p
      on co.subject_id = p.person_id
```

I understand row_number function is used to generate the row numbers but looks like Postgresql doesn't support all these functions like `Checksum` and `MD5`.

I get the below error

```
ERROR:  function checksum(text) does not exist
LINE 2:    row_number() over (order by ABS(CHECKSUM(MD5(RANDOM()::TE...
                                           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 54
```

How can I avoid the above error and make this work in postgresql?

Comment: You can avoid the error by only using functions that are [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html)

Comment: May I know what does `RANDOM::TEXT` do? Is there anyway to execute and see what `RANDOM::TEXT` looks like or `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()::TEXT`

Comment: `::` is a type cast. Look into the documentation for the other functions. There is no `checksum` function in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you would use `random()`:

```
select co.*, p.*,
       row_number() over (order by random()) as rn
from s1.depat co join
     s2.person p
     on co.subject_id = p.person_id;
```

The use of `checksum()` suggests that the query generator thinks you are connected to SQL Server.  There is probably a parameter somewhere to let it know to generate valid Postgres code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. But what about MD5. MD5 works in postgres though but it can't be used as sequence number. Right? It turns it into a string?

Comment: @TheGreat . . . You can use `MD5()` if you are looking for a repeatable sequence.  But SQL Server requires the chains of functions, because it doesn't have a simple `random()` function that gets called for every row.